# Restrict using WRAP_CONTENT and MATCH_PARENT in CustomView

Tags: android, xml

I'm stuck with one problem. I have a simple CustomView that **must** have the exact size. In other words `height` and `width` should never be `WRAP_CONTENT` or `MATCH_PARENT`.

What did I try or think about

I can't just throw an exception inside the `onMeasure` method because it can crash the app in release mode. I can't just call exception inside `BuildConfig.DEBUG` check, because it is a separate library and I can achieve it only with reflection, that is bad since my CustomView will have many instances (in lists for example).

I didn't find any way how can I just override height/width and restrict constants and I didn't find an example of how to make lint check for compile-time that looks for XML layouts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello. Can't you just ignore the params that are set in xml and just hardcode needed dimens inside the view?

Comment: @PaulOst unfortunately not - I have to be sure that user didnt forget to set proper values =(

Comment: @AndreyDanilov, unfortunately, there isn't way to make it as you want. The best way is to ignore these values or throw up exception. Ugly way is to write custom `width` and `height` properties. If it will be used with data binding then you can write own adapter to accept only valid sizes.

Comment: @Шах so there is no lint checks for layouts, right?

Comment: @AndreyDanilov there are lint checks for layouts, but you will need to write separate lint library for your custom view and force users to include it along with the library itself. I am not sure though that lint will do what you want - in the best case it will raise a warning but not an error - so the user will be able to ignore it.

Comment: @AndreyDanilov, if you just provide a simple Android library with custom view, no, there isn't.